# Matching an IP address with an IP range?

Tags: php, mysql, language-agnostic, networking, ip

I have a MySQL table setup as follows:

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ipaddress_s   | varchar(15) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| ipaddress_e   | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

where, ipaddress_s and ipaddress_e look something like: 4.100.159.0-4.100.159.255

Now is there a way I can actually get the row that contains a given IP address? For instance, given the IP address: "4.100.159.5", I want the above row to be returned. So I am trying for a query that looks something like this (but of course this is wrong because in the following I am considering IPs as strings):

```
SELECT * FROM ranges WHERE ipaddress_s<"4.100.159.5" AND ipaddress_e>"4.100.159.5"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

INET_ATON(expr) will change an ip address string into a numeric address that you can use for comparison.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton

```
SELECT * FROM ranges WHERE INET_ATON(ipaddress_s)<INET_ATON('4.100.159.0') AND INET_ATON(ipaddress_e)>INET_ATON('4.100.159.5')
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even know those functions existed!

Comment: Yup... if performance is an issue, you might store the addresses in the database as integers in the first place.

Comment: Yeah.. In the process of dropping this table and creating a new one :)

Comment: See INET_NTOA() for convenience when you get that far =)

Comment: Using both the functions extensively :) You simplified my life essentially... Thanks once again...!