# Get the location from the DB-IP database against our IP addlist

Tags: mysql, ip-address

We downloaded this IP address list with location/country from DB-IP.com.

The structured data that they have as follow and as you can see it's range and it's not individual IP. We called this IPAddress_table.

```
IPStart; IPEnd; Country; State; City
0.0.0.0 0.255.255.255   US  California  Los Angeles
1.0.0.0 1.0.0.255   AU  Queensland  South Brisbane
1.0.1.0 1.0.3.255   CN  Fujian  Fuzhou
1.0.4.0 1.0.7.255   AU  Victoria    Melbourne
1.0.8.0 1.0.15.255  CN  Guangdong   Guangzhou
```

In our database users (user_table), we have more 100,000+ users with IP address.

How do I join these 2 tables in MySQL cause the IP address source is range start-end?

I'm appreciated your feedback.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703060/matching-an-ip-address-with-an-ip-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
Assuming table names are IPAddress_table and user_table
Assuming Field Names are:
user_table : IPAddress (and others), 
IPAddress_table: IPStart, IPEnd (and others)
```

SQL to try:

```
SELECT user_table.*, IPAddress_table.*
FROM user_table 
  INNER JOIN IPAddress_table 
    ON INET_ATON(user_table.IPAddress) 
      BETWEEN INET_ATON(IPAddress_table.IPStart) 
        AND INET_ATON(IPAddress_table.IPEnd)
```

Edit: You might want to change it to be LEFT JOIN to get all users even IP range is not found to fit.

Comment: Didn't realise that there is function for that - INET_ATON. Will try this. Thanks

Comment: sure. please try it and let us know. I know it will work as needed because I tested it with your table structure before sending it. However, 100000+ records might cause a slow query, which is another side of the subject.